# Is there any device for measuring phase and gain of a device in frequency range as low as 0.1 Hz?

Tags: gain, phase, vna

I need to measure phase and gain of a circuit starting from 0.1 Hz to 10 MHz. Most of VNAs are for frequencies of several MHz to GHz. I've just found one VNA for 1 Hz.
Is there a device or method to measure even lower frequencies?

Comment: What is the circuit in question?

Comment: A tricky amplifier with a passband from 0.1 to 100 Hz and filters at some specific frequencies

Comment: I would consider using an oscilloscope. Be careful that the high pass cutoff frequencies of any AC coupling you use is below the frequency at which you want to measure. A non-analog waveform generator should be able to generate a low frequency sinusoidal signal.

Comment: Frequency response analyser.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie of cource I could use a low frequency generator and a scope or something to measure amplitude of 0.1Hz sine, but this is veeeeeery long. So I need some equipement to make this automatically. May be some device, that sends a step and measures a step responce and then converts it to phase an amplitude characteristic or whatever

Comment: My suggestion assumes that the low frequency equipment either isn't available or too expensive. It is possible to automate what I suggest and then the measurement will take just as long as a suitable VNA would need. If you're familiar with Python and SCPI commands making a program to do the measurements in an automated way is do-able.

Comment: I've used python with a PC sound card to do audio phase measurements. I wonder whether there are any DC-coupled cards, or cards that could be modified easily by shorting across any AC coupling capacitors? Less hacky, my Rigol scope can capture its waveforms to file, I would wager that most makes of digital scope will do that these days, which gets you a DC-coupled capture of input and output waveforms that you have already seen, into a program to compute phase. You could even compute phase in Excel.

Comment: Both phase and amplitude at 0.1Hz can be measured with an eyeball on the oscilloscope and stopwatch in-hand. A modern digital 'scope that saves the traces on-screen makes it even easier.

Comment: _"I need to measure phase and gain of a circuit starting from 0.1 Hz to 10 MHz"_ why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get a hold of (rent or buy used) an HP/Agilent 3562A dynamic signal analyzer, it can handle the job from 64uHz to 100kHz.  You can use a conventional frequency response analyzer for the higher frequency range.

I got one years ago for $400 on eBay, but there are ones in better shape easily available (for more $$):

[3562A](https://www.testequipmentdepot.com/products.htm?item=3562A-U&ref=gbase&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5cmtgOX25gIVFL3sCh0OpwI7EAQYASABEgKn5fD_BwE)

Of course your measurement time for sub 1Hz testing is going to be long if you need a lot of points.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a signal source and a DDS-based lock-in amplifier such as the SR830 which covers up to about 100kHz. Not sure about buying a used one, though, I recall that at one time their policy on support was not favorable to 2nd hand purchasers.

Of course if you can get the data into digital form in some way (digitize input and output voltages synchronized and with sufficient resolution and sample rate), you can do the calculations in any computer, with C or Scilab or Matlab or whatever.